# When does twig calls php function before loading or after loading DOM?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, twig

I am calling a php function from the twig template like

`{% if ($someThing) {
      {{ getValues() }}
}%}`

```
{% if ($otherThing) {
     {{ getMoreValues() }}
} %}
```

`getValues() {
  $cookie = /* gets cookie from request */;
  fetchingValues($cookie);
 }`

```
getMoreValues() {
    $cookie = ' /*gets same cookie as getValues() */
    fetchingValues($cookie);
 }
```

both functions getValues and getMoreValues further calls same function in the php code say fetchingValues($cookie).

This fetchingValues modifies the $cookie and sets it. Thing is after setting the cookie from getValues(). When fetchingValues gets called from getMoreValues it get $cookie as a empty string. or say getMoreValues getting $cookie as a empty string.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: get cockies by javascript. You set cookie hes write in you browser, but not write in $_COOKIE because you browser not set the cookie in this request, he only get in response.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say, setcookie() won't set the cookie for browser ?

Comment: Sorry I bad speak English... Browser set Request to server and get Response. When you call setcookie() you set in Response `Cookie:key=value&test=23`. After browser get the response, and set to new request `Cookie:key=value&test=23`, and you can get the cookie in your script.

Comment: I find simple graph for you http://cscie12.dce.harvard.edu/lecture_notes/2011/20110504/images/http_cookie1.png about how to work http and cookie